# Android: write a class for using alert dialog every where

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I am new in android and I have tried to write a class `MyAlertDialog` for alert dialog to use it every where I need an alert dialog. I have written a method `showAlertDialog` in the class to do this. I found that the method have to be static. Could anybody tell me why it should be static? Here is my code:

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AppCompatActivity {

public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message) {

    final Dialog dialog;
    TextView txtAlertMsg;
    TextView txtAlertOk;

    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_alert_dialog);
    txtAlertOk = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtAalertOk);
    txtAlertMsg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertMsg);
    txtAlertMsg.setText(message);
    txtAlertOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

and I have called it like bellow:

```
MyAlertDialog.alertDialogShow(MainActivity.this,"Here is my message");
```

Comment: it shouldn't be static but most of the dev make it static to save the time of creating a new instance of the class to call it.

Comment: If you do not make it static you would have to call it like `new MyAlertDialog().alertDialogShow(MainActivity.this,"Here is my message");`.

Comment: you can use `public class MyAlertDialog extends DialogFragment` [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment)

Comment: `public class MyAlertDialog extends AppCompatActivity`. That is completely wrong. You do not need to extend, `public class MyAlertDialog` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to be static

You can also do it the non-static way:

```
public class MyAlertDialog {

private Context context;
private String message;

public MyAlertDialog(Context context,String message){
    this.context = context;
    this.message = message;
}

public void alertDialogShow() {

    final Dialog dialog;
    TextView txtAlertMsg;
    TextView txtAlertOk;

    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_alert_dialog);
    txtAlertOk = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtAalertOk);
    txtAlertMsg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertMsg);
    txtAlertMsg.setText(message);
    txtAlertOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show(); 
}
```

To call it:

```
MyAlertDialog myAlertDialog = new MyAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"Here is my message");

myAlertDialog.alertDialogShow();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works in this way too.But I want to know which solution is better?

Answer (score 2):

Why it should be static?

For memory management

How?

Declaring a field static means only one instance of it will exists

It does not belong to a specific instance, they can't refer to instance members, meaning they belong to the class itself